# SQL double select in one table (statement: find out who's the owner of a file)

Tags: sql, select

It might be an easy question, but I cannot figure it out.

My table looks like this:

```
user_id     file_id     permission
----------------------------------
0           0           OWNER
0           1           OWNER
1           2           OWNER
1           0           READ
2           0           WRITE
2           2           READ
```

I want to create a statement, which returns the following for an user:

```
owner       file        permission
```

Example for user 2:

```
owner       file        permission
----------------------------------
0           0           WRITE
1           2           READ
```

Can you give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Strange data structure.  You can do what you want with a `join`:

```
select towner.user_id, t.file_id, t.permission
from table t join
     table towner
     on t.file_id = towner.file_id and towner.permission = 'OWNER'
where t.user_id = 2;
```

Comment: Can you suggest different structure?

Comment: @CeruleanKnight . . . It seems strange to me to have the file ownership in the same table as the permissions.  Once I understood this, the structure makes sense.  But I'm still thinking that ownership is different from the other permissions.  One is a property of the file and the other is a property of a user and a file.

Comment: I have little experience in SQL, but our professor said that, we should avoid "loops". If a file has an owner_id column it creates a "loop", because there is also a table, containing user_id, which refers to the user. That way we destroy the tree structure. But clearly, this is a way better method of solving this problem.